# How to install and use at job scheduling?

Tags: linux, scheduling, at

I am not clear on the following:
Is the process for `at` available to all linux installations? Or do would I need to do something to "install" it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on your Linux distribution and the kind of installation (minimal, desktop-centric, etc.) `at`  (and `atd` the at job scheduler daemon) is installed by default or not.

To verify it you can issue commands like:

```
$ which at
/usr/bin/at
$ which atd
/usr/bin/atd
$ yum whatprovides atd # to get the package name 
$ yum info pkg-name # to see if it is installed
```

(assuming yum is available on Suse - using a Fedora system here)

If the package is not installed you can install it via your package manager, e.g. something like:

```
$ yum install at # on fedora at least
```

If it is installed, perhaps the daemon is not started on bootup by default.

To see if it running:

```
$ pgrep -l atd
```

Or just test it like this

```
$ echo echo hello world | at now
```

(watch your system logs in another terminal and/or check your local mailbox)

How to start it depends on your init-system, if it is old-school it would be something like:

```
$ /etc/init.d/atd start
```

If it is systemd it would be something like:

```
$ systemctl start atd
```

For a init.d based system as well for the systemd one there are also commands to display the status of a service like atd and to make it startup on boot.

But most likely `atd` is started by default after installation and it is setup by default to be started at system boot.

Comment: FWIW, a package called `at` also exists in various other packaging systems, as well... so on a system without `yum`, one might have success with `sudo apt install at` or other such things.

Answer (score 2):

Essential on [most systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29), is a daemon, usually `atd`

Comment: I was looking through a book on SUSE and it said "You can use YaST to add at to the current run level." So I could not figure out what this means and if I would have `at` available in any system I run my script or not

Comment: To see if it's running, try 'ps aux | grep atd'. To check if it's installed, use 'whereis atd'. To see if it's set to run on boot, that depends on the init system you're using. Hope this is helpful.